# How do I install an HP home-use printer on Windows Home Server (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: drivers, printer, windows-server-2003, windows-home-server

I have an HP DeskJet F4210 printer that I would like to share on my network via Windows Home Server. Unfortunately, the driver installation checks for supported OS's, detects Home Server as Windows Server 2003 and exits. The driver install supports WinXP, W2k, Vista, and Win98SE.

In theory, drivers for XP or Windows 2000 should work fine with Home Server. When using the "Install Printer" tool in Home Server I am only able to select .inf files (there are serveral on the install media) but the driver folders for XP and 2000 have .sys and .dll files.

How can I bypass HP's short-sighted install program and get this printer up and running on Home server? I'll be happy with basic print functionality and will save the task of enabling scanning for another time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you download an executable (.exe) from HP? If the installer is what is closing down, download and install [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) (fully usable trial version) and you can extract the files from the installer to a folder on your computer. From there, you can find the .inf files and install the print driver on your computer.

I do this all the time at work.

Comment: Perfect. It took a couple of tries to find the right .inf, but the method worked perfectly. Oh, and I have long since replaced WinRAR with 7Zip - the shell extension alone is worth the download. http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: I assumed 7-zip would work but I knew WinRAR did. Glad I could help!

Comment: The only thing that has tripped up 7-zip for me are stuff-it archives but 7-Zip has gone through a few versions since then.